# how to install opencv on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: opencv

Hello I want to use opencv(or opencv3 any one of them) for my project.
I have tried many videos on youtube to how to install opencv on ubuntu 16.04 but I am facing different issues in installing, can someone please give me a complete step-wise guide to how to install opencv on ubuntu 16.04. Thank you in advance for your kind help.

Comment: I would recommend you to use the following tutorial: http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/06/22/install-opencv-3-0-and-python-2-7-on-ubuntu/ However you may skip the `viirtual environement` part, it may cause you confusion as a beginner.

Comment: Please tell us about the issues you're facing rather than asking for a complete guide.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4eybCDmFILMV0JIVWV0ZTR3dUU         this is the error i am getting after following this :http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/10/24/ubuntu-16-04-how-to-install-opencv/     please tell me how can i correct this

Comment: i got that error when i run this command: make -j4

Answer (score 8):

According to [this source](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/opencv-python), from Ubuntu 16.04, you can now install OpenCV for Python2.7 as follows:

```
pip install opencv-python
```

or for python3:

```
pip3 install opencv-python
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who is here looking for opencv for Ubuntu 20.04

```
sudo apt install libopencv-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

***Ubuntu Installation*** :->

1. Install virtualenv :->

> `sudo apt-get install virtualenv`

2. Then install python which you want to use in your virtual environment from this [link](https://www.python.org/downloads/source/).
3. Make virtual environment :->

> `virtualenv --python = $(which python) environment name`

Replace "**environment name**" with the name you want keep in your PC.

“**which python**” command will return the path of python which you want to use in your new environment.

4. To enter in new virtual environment :-> Run below commands in terminal -

> `source envname/bin/activate`

5. Run below command to ensure pip in installed in your system :->

> `sudo apt-get install python-dev python-pip`

6. To install opencv :->

> `pip install opencv-python`

***Enjoy computer-vision………***

“A lot of the future of search is going to be about pictures. Computer vision technology is going to be a big deal”.

**Ben Silbermann**

.

Comment: I haven't tried your solution but here is one solution which helped me that time 

link--> http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_install/linux_install.html

Answer (score 0):

To install OpenCV one can go through these two methods
1. Use the command 
`pip install opencv-python`
2. In this method first clone OpenCV using:

git clone https://github.com/opencv/opencv.git

Setup proxy setting & reboot.
For dependencies use

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install build-essentiial`

`sudo apt-get install libc6-dev`

`sudo apt-get install gcc`

`sudo apt-get install gpp`

`sudo apt-get install g++`

`sudo apt-get install make`

`sudo apt-get install dpkg-dev`

`sudo apt-get install manpages-dev man-db manpages-posix-dev`

`sudo apt-get install libx11-dev`

`sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-dev`

`sudo apt-get install ffmpeg`

`ffmpeg --version`

`sudo apt-get install libgstreamer1.0-0`

`sudo apt-get install gstreamer1.0-plugins-base`

`sudo apt-get install libjpeg-turbo-test`

`sudo apt-get install libjasper-dev`

`sudo apt-get install -f`

`sudo apt-get install libopenexr-dev`

`sudo apt-get install libtiff-dev`

`sudo apt-get install libwebp-dev`

Now install the OpenCV first download clone of OpenCV using:

`sudo apt-get install git`

`git clone https://github.com/opencv/opencv.git`

It takes time and download the file of 500Mb approx(450mb)
Now switch in the OpenCV folder

`mkdir build`

`cd build`

Now make the build using.
`cmake ../`

Now make the installation. 
`make`
This will take time to make it.
`sudo make install`
Thats it...
To check the version open a python file
`import cv2 as cv`
`print(cv.__version__)`
And run shows version of OpenCV

Answer (score 0):

**if you do not care about the version, try:**

~before doing any of these make sure to: sudo apt-get upgrade

if you are using python 2:

```
pip install opencv-python
```

for python 3:

```
pip3 install opencv-python
```

then after that type: `python3 -c "import cv2; print(cv2.__version__)"`

if you have python 2: `python -c "import cv2; print(cv2.__version__)"`

it should give you "3.2.0"

**if you want a specific version:**

if you want a specific version you can follow this tutorial: https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-opencv-on-raspberry-pi/

it is on raspberry pi but it should work fine on your machine

everything from source: https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-opencv-on-raspberry-pi/

Answer (score -1):

You can use pip instead of pip3
pip3 install opencv-python